# integration oGone Payment service with Java

Tags: payment-gateway

I have to integrate "oGone Payment service" with Java. For example, User need to buy some items through "oGone Payment service" ( like PayPal). How to pass all my parameters to "oGone Payment service".If anybody could throw some torch on this, it will be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

just follow the ogone documentation. If you want to use direct link I suggest to use the spring RestTemplate.

```
<!-- rest template -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" id="restTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="formMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="stringMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"
    id="stringMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"
    id="formMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="DirectLinkTemplateImpl" id="directLinkTemplate">
    <property name="restTemplate" ref="restTemplate"></property>
    <property name="url"
        value="https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/test/orderdirect.asp"></property>
    <property name="pspId" value="YOR PSP ID"></property>
    <property name="userId" value="userID"></property>
    <property name="pswd" value="pass"></property>
    <property name="shaPassphrase" value="shaPassphrase"></property>
</bean>
```

Then use code similar to the following to post to ogone

```
    /**
     * This class abstracts the functionality of the OGONE direct link payment api making use of Springs {@link RestTemplate}
     * 
     * 
     * @author Kai Grabfelder (nospam@kaigrabfelder.de)
     *
     */
    public class DirectLinkTemplateImpl implements DirectLinkTemplate {

    private RestOperations restTemplate;

    private String shaPassphrase; 

    private String url;
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    /**
     * affiliation name in ogone.
     */
    private String pspId;
    /**
     * Name of ogone application (API) user.
     */
    private String userId;
    /**
     * Password of the API user (USERID).
     */
    private String pswd;

    public RestOperations getRestTemplate() {
        return restTemplate;
    }

    public void setRestTemplate(RestOperations restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPswd() {
        return pswd;
    }

    public void setPswd(String pswd) {
        this.pswd = pswd;
    }



    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see DirectLinkTemplate#executeDirectLinkRequest(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void executeDirectLinkRequest(int amount, String currency,
            String orderId, String alias) {


        Map<String, String> request = new HashMap<String, String>();
        request.put("PSPID", getPspId());
        request.put("USERID", getUserId());
        request.put("PSWD", getPswd());
        request.put("AMOUNT", String.valueOf(amount));
        request.put("CURRENCY", currency);
        request.put("ORDERID", orderId);
        request.put("ALIAS", alias);
        request.put("ECI", "9"); //set the ECI parameter to 9 (recurring payment) - necessary according to ogone support

        request = cleanupRequestParameters(request);

        String shaSign = composeSHASIGNParameter(request);
        request.put("SHASIGN", shaSign);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>>(createMultiValueMap(request), headers );


        String response = restTemplate.postForObject(getUrl(), entity, String.class);

        //TODO validate response
        System.out.println(response);



    }

    private MultiValueMap<String, String> createMultiValueMap(Map<String, String> map){
        map = new TreeMap<String, String>(map);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            multiValueMap.add(key, map.get(key));
        }
        return multiValueMap;
    }


    /**
     * cleanup the request parameters by removing all parameters with an empty value and converting all parameter names to upper case
     * 
     * @param request
     * @return 
     */
    protected Map<String, String> cleanupRequestParameters(Map<String, String> request){

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Set<String> keys = request.keySet();
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = keys.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            String value = request.get(key);
            if (StringUtils.hasText(value)) map.put(key.toUpperCase(), value);
        }

        return map ;
    }



    /**
     * create the SHASign parameter according to the specification of ogone: sorts all keys alphabetically,
     * @param request
     * @return
     */
    protected String composeSHASIGNParameter(Map<String, String> request){

        //create a map with alphabetically sorted keys
        TreeMap<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(request);

        Set<String> keys = sortedMap.keySet();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key : keys) {
            sb.append(key).append("=").append(request.get(key));
            sb.append(getShaPassphrase());
        }

        MessageDigest md;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        byte[] digest = md.digest(sb.toString().getBytes());

        String encodedString = new String(Hex.encodeHex(digest));
        return encodedString;
    }

    public String getShaPassphrase() {
        return shaPassphrase;
    }

    public void setShaPassphrase(String shaPassphrase) {
        this.shaPassphrase = shaPassphrase;
    }

    public String getPspId() {
        return pspId;
    }

    public void setPspId(String pspId) {
        this.pspId = pspId;
    }

}
```

I'm not yet finished with the implementation but at least the "post to ogone" part works already. I'll try to post the complete DirectLinkTemplate in my blog once it is finished and cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of it. it may work or not [jOgone](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jogone/). A java library written for Ogone