# Integration of Ogone payments with alias support

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, payment-gateway

I have problems with [Ogone](http://www.ogone.com/) Payment provider.
My task is to integrate this payment method, but with alias support, not with credit card number support.

I have searched several times for samples and solutions, also in the Ogone support documentation, but withoud success.
[Example1](http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-830-ogone-payment-gateway.aspx)[Example2](http://support.cheddargetter.com/kb/getting-started-19/configuring-ogone)[Example3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394944/integration-ogone-payment-service-withjava)

My question is: Is there a webservice or open web api for making request to Ogone? Did anyone have found samples for this provider writen in C#?

Comment: I have found a way of resolving this problem. I will publish it soon, when ai Have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answert of my question.
There are the steps for simple Ogone Payment.

1. Download Ogone Direct Link Guide from [here](http://www.productivecomputing.com/docs/docs_library/FM_CreditCard/Ogone_DirectLink_EN.pdf).
2. Download Ogone Alias Manager Integration Guide from [here](https://secure.ogone.com/Ncol/Ogone_Alias_EN.pdf).
3. Try to read them, because all of the info are inside of them.
4. Find the URL to make request to. Ex: https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp
5. Post data to the url like in this [example](http://www.iamraghuveer.com/2011/10/posting-data-to-url-in-cnet.html).
6. The data should include several important components and must be similar to this:

   "PSPID=username&
   ALIASUSAGE=Test&
   ORDERID=OrderId&
   AMOUNT=Price*10&
   CURRENCY=EUR&
   ALIAS=GUID&
   LANGUAGE=en_EN&
   ACCEPTURL=SomeUrl&
   EXCEPTIONURL=SomeUrl&
   DECLINEURL=SomeUrl&
   SHASIGN=SHA1EncriptedPhrase"

The SHASIGN is encripted passphrase that is taken from the OgoneBackoffice.

7. If response successd, then you should recieve an Html page.
   Put the reponse into an IFRAME or where you want. This is the page for payment.
   If there are some issues, please read the Direct Link Guide for them.
   After successful payment the user will be redirected to the links in the request.

For More question, please comment.